# Frameworks of distributed test

Tags: perl, testing, distributed-system

I'm searching for some frameworks for distributed job execution based on **Perl** or **Python**. Here's the thing:

In my team we have to run about a thousand regression tests per week to make sure the new release works well. At first all these tests were run on a single machine, but now we have more PCs so we would like to build up a cluster and distribute all the tests onto several PCs. The tests are written in Perl and organized by XML. I did some research but only found some frameworks of Java, which I'm totally not familiar with. Is there some other distributed frameworks in Perl or Python, or simply some articles describing such a system that I could re-implement? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use gearman to run commands (jobs) on many machines. the code part could be really simple:

```
use Gearman::Worker;
my $worker = Gearman::Worker->new;
$worker->job_servers('127.0.0.1');
$worker->register_function($funcname => &do_job);
$worker->work while 1;
sub do_job {
  print "Do something!\n";
}
```

[using_gearman_for_nightly_build_and_test](http://www.tokutek.com/2009/10/using_gearman_for_nightly_build_and_test/)

http://www.slideshare.net/andy.sh/gearman-and-perl

http://search.cpan.org/~dormando/Gearman-Server-1.11/gearmand

http://gearman.org/